# Provision of services or realization?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage

Does this sentence make sense? Is term 'provision of services' used correctly or should I use 'realization of services'?

'Versatile machinery guarantees provision of services to the most demanding customers, such as .....'

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes sense, meaning Machinery guarantees [that] services will be provided [to even] the most demanding customers . . . .

A wording closer to mine may be considered as a more straightforward style, but your example is grammatical and makes sense.

The first example below shows a similar use.

[image: Some googled examples]